# Maximise the minimum difference

Tags: algorithm

We are given N elements in form of array A , Now we have to choose K indexes from N given indexes such that for any 2 indexes i and j minimum value of |A[i]-A[j]| is as large as possible. We need to tell this maximum value.

Lets take an example : Let N=5 and K=2 and array be [1,5,3,7,11] then here answer is 10 as we can simply choose first and last position and differ = 11-1=10.

Example 2 : Let N=10 and K=3 and array A be [3 9 6 11 15 20 23] then here answer will be 8. As we can select [3,11,23] or [3,15,23].

Now given N , K and Array A we need to find this maximum difference.

We are given that 1 ≤ N ≤ 10^5 and 1 ≤ S ≤ 10^7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Let's sort the array.
2. Now we can do a binary search over the answer.
3. For a fixed candidate `x`, we can just pick the elements greedily(iterating over the sorted array and taking each element if we can). If the number of elements we have picked is not less than `K`, `x` is feasible. Otherwise, it is not.

The time complexity is `O(N * log N + N * log (MAX_ELEMENT - MIN_ELEMENT))`

A pseudo code:

```
bool isFeasible(int x):
    cnt = 1
    last = a[0]
    for i <- 1 ... n - 1:
        if a[i] - last >= x:
            last = a[i]
            cnt++
    return cnt >= k

sort(a)
low = 0
high = a[n - 1] - a[0] + 1
while high - low > 1:
    mid = low + (high - low) / 2
    if isFeasible(mid):
       low = mid
    else
       high = mid
print(low)
```

Comment: Can you provide pseudocode for your algorithm

Comment: @user3840069 I've just added it.

Comment: Why isFeasible(int x): as you had not used x anywhere

Comment: @user3840069 There was a bug, it should be fixed now.

Comment: for first case it is giving 9 and not 10

Comment: @user3840069 I checked it. It gives 10.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be dealt with as a dynamic programming problem. Start off by sorting A, and then the problem is to mark K elements in A such that the minimum difference between adjacent marked items is as large as possible. As a starter, you can always mark the first and last elements.

Moving from left to right, at each position for i=1..N work out the largest minimum difference you can get by marking i elements in the sub-array terminating at this position. You can work out the largest minimum difference for k items terminating at this position by considering the largest minimum difference for k-1 items terminating at each position to the left of the position you are working on. The obvious thing to do is to consider each possible position up to the position you are currently working on as ending a stretch of k-1 items with minimum difference, but you may be able to do a binary search here to speed things up.

Once you have worked all the way to the right hand end you know the maximum possible value for the original problem. If you need to know where to put the K elements, you can take notes as you go along so that you can backtrack to find out the elements chosen that lead to this solution, working from right to left.